# How are fuel/hydraulics pipes coupled in spacecraft?

Tags: rockets, fuel, liquid-fuel

How are pipes coupled in spacecraft? 
I found Shape memory alloy pipe couplings ([SCoup](https://artes.esa.int/funding/shape-memory-coupling-connecting-pipes-artes-51-4e060-expro), see image taken from [link](https://books.google.be/books?id=5NyH0h1OgisC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=sma%20pipe%20coupling%20space&source=bl&ots=r8WI8kJd78&sig=ACfU3U3wxexBLJW0l2GkpBxPKq8o9EgQCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDvP_zuZ_oAhVKCewKHXSuBT04ChDoATAAegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=sma%20pipe%20coupling%20space&f=false)) are sometimes used.

-Is this still the case and in what quantity are they used?

-What are the alternative coupling methods considering weight and reliability are constraints.

[image: SMA pipe coupling]

Answer (score 11):

The 1976 NASA monograph *[Liquid Rocket Disconnects, Couplings, Fittings, Fixed Joints, and Seals](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19770017247.pdf)*  defines "couplings" as

> Couplings are manually actuated separable connectors that require more
>   than a few seconds for engagement or disengagement.

and lists the following types:

- Flanged

[image]

- Threaded:

[image]

- Dynamic swivel couplings

Shape memory alloy is not mentioned, but that may be a newer development.

Comment: Is Swagelok common?